# OpenCV Fisheye Calibration giving large error on identical points

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, fisheye

I'm trying to correct for fisheye in an image using OpenCV.

I can't get the calibration step to work. I've tried the code below to calibrate, and even with identical x and y coordinates in the input and output, the returned rms is at least 100.

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3d>> objpts;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2d>> imgpts;
cv::Size img_size(1292,964); //dimension of input image in pixels
cv::Mat K, D;
std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs, tvecs;

objpts.push_back(std::vector<cv::Point3d>());
imgpts.push_back(std::vector<cv::Point2d>());

//loading identical data into each
objpts[0].push_back(cv::Point3d(100, 100, 0));
objpts[0].push_back(cv::Point3d(0, 100, 0));
objpts[0].push_back(cv::Point3d(100, 0, 0));
objpts[0].push_back(cv::Point3d(0, 0, 0));
objpts[0].push_back(cv::Point3d(0, 50, 0));

imgpts[0].push_back(cv::Point2d(100, 100));
imgpts[0].push_back(cv::Point2d(0, 100));
imgpts[0].push_back(cv::Point2d(100, 0));
imgpts[0].push_back(cv::Point2d(0, 0));
imgpts[0].push_back(cv::Point2d(0, 50));

//ret changes depending on the points, but is always around 100-500
double ret = cv::fisheye::calibrate(objpts, imgpts, img_size, K, D, rvecs, tvecs);

//This produces the images seen below
cv::Mat im = cv::imread("env.jpg");
cv::Mat out;
cv::fisheye::undistortImage(im, out, K, D);
cv::imwrite("out_env.jpg", out);
```

When I try to use these calibrated K and D matrices to undistort an image, I get results that look like this:
[image: out_image]

For reference, here's the source image:
[image: in_image]

I got similar issues when I tried using actual pixel coordinates for imgpts and physical dimensions for objpts.

Using opencv 3.4.5

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: would ifentical points be orthogonal projection??

Comment: I think it should correspond to no distortion, so the real world coordinates map exactly into pixel coordinates, right?